# Why is Python3 slower than Python2?

Tags: python, benchmarking

I have seen some benchmark graphs while googling that represents Python is faster and consumes less memory than Python3.

Here is the link to the article: https://raid6.com.au/~onlyjob/posts/arena/

(Sorry that I cannot post an image due to lack of reputations.)

I've seen some questions and answers in stackoverflow, but some people are saying Python3 is rather faster. So I am curious to know the truth.

Are those graphs and charts true? or is it not viable now?

Comment: Python 3 when it first came out was significantly slower than Python 2. These days, I find the difference between them negligible or weighted towards python 3 though. The article you linked is from 2012, and is therefore most likely completely out of date.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I've noticed that. I was wondering if that is still viable because the architecture of a language does not really change over time anyway. But I guess that experiment itself was not fair.

Comment: @HumbleCoder: The actual interpreter that interprets it at runtime can change a *lot*.  e.g. look at very early Java vs. current JVMs which can sometimes even auto-vectorize with SIMD when just-in-time compiling.  Or look at very early C when optimizing compilers didn't even exist, vs. modern gcc and clang that can do things like recognize a `for(i=0..n) sum += i;` loop and compile it into asm that uses the closed-form `n*(n+1) /2`.  Or a less extreme example, modern C++ compilers speculatively de-virtualizing `virtual` functions.  Better implementation of the same language can be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all benchmarks are flawed, this one is more so than most.

1. These test results are from 2011. Software has not stood still since then. Current versions of Python 3 perform comparably with Python 2.7, if not better. Similarly, modern versions of the other languages in this benchmark will likely outperform the versions which were tested.
2. The operations being performed in this benchmark are pretty strange (repeatedly appending to a string, then performing search-and-replace operations on it). They aren't representative of the overall performance of a language.

Comment: Would you mind giving me some other viable comparisons other than the one I've posted?

Comment: @HumbleCoder - you can try posting your question on meta stackexchange as well for more relevant answers like the ones above.